# throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' what(): basic_string::at_n __n >= this->size()

Tags: c++

I'm not able to pass a string to a function.
Actually I can build & run my program but it gives me this error (I typed in 'spoon'):

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what(): basic_string::at_n __n (which is 5) >= this->size() (which is 5)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I want to build a program being able to recognize different keywords in a question and answering

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int result;

//returns value of the analysation case
int analyze(string w)
{
    if(w == "knife"){return 1;}
    if(w == "spoon"){return 2;}
    if(w == "fork"){return 3;}
    return 0;
}

int main ()
{
    string input;
    cin >> input;
    for(int pos = 0; pos < input.length(); pos++) //as long the current letter is within the string
        {
            string word = "";           //resetting stored word
            while(input.at(pos) != ' ') //as long the current letter is not a space => goes trough a whole word
            {
                word += input.at(pos);  //add the current letter to the current word
                pos ++;
            }
            int result = analyze(word);    //gets word analyzation result
        }

    switch(result)
    {
        case 1:
            cout << "do something (1)"; break;
        case 2:
            cout << "do something (2)"; break;
        case 3:
            cout << "do something (3)"; break;
        default:
            cout << "I do not understand";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Additional I'm not able to pass 'result' trough the for()-loop. I read that the compiler would destroy all functions used in the for()-loop but I don't know how to fix it. Using while() neither works for me.Hope you can help me -Thank you :)

Comment: You declared `result` inside of the `for` loop scope. Declare it before the loop.

Answer (score 1):

[`vector::at()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) will throw if you try to acces out of bounds.

The problem is that you increment `pos` and check for space. What if your input string does not have space?

```
while(input.at(pos) != ' ') /* You should also abort when pos >= input.length() */
{
    word += input.at(pos);  //add the current letter to the current word
    pos ++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This loop:

```
while(input.at(pos) != ' ') //as long the current letter is not a space => goes trough a whole word
{
     word += input.at(pos);  //add the current letter to the current word
     pos ++;
}
```

Will, if the string contains no spaces (or no more spaces), go past the end of the string. At that point, `input.at` causes the exception to be thrown. You need to check if you have reached the end of your string here!